# Finding the maximum difference for a subset of columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
   A   B    C   D   E
0  a  34   55  43  aa
1  b  53   77  65  bb
2  c  23  100  34  cc
3  d  54   43  23  dd
4  e  23   67  54  ee
5  f  43   98  23  ff
```

I need to get the maximum difference between the column B,C and D and return the value in column A . in row 'a' maximum difference  between columns is 55 - 34 = 21 . data is in a dataframe.

The expected result is

```
    A   B    C   D   E
0  21  34   55  43  aa
1  24  53   77  65  bb
2  77  23  100  34  cc
3  31  54   43  23  dd
4  44  23   67  54  ee
5  75  43   98  23  ff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
# df['A'] = np.ptp(df.loc[:, 'B':'D'], axis=1)
df['A'] = np.ptp(df[['B', 'C', 'D']], axis=1)
df

    A   B    C   D   E
0  21  34   55  43  aa
1  24  53   77  65  bb
2  77  23  100  34  cc
3  31  54   43  23  dd
4  44  23   67  54  ee
5  75  43   98  23  ff
```

---

Or, find the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) yourself:

```
df['A'] = df[['B', 'C', 'D']].max(1) - df[['B', 'C', 'D']].min(1)
df

    A   B    C   D   E
0  21  34   55  43  aa
1  24  53   77  65  bb
2  77  23  100  34  cc
3  31  54   43  23  dd
4  44  23   67  54  ee
5  75  43   98  23  ff
```

If performance is important, you can do this in NumPy space:

```
v = df[['B', 'C', 'D']].values
df['A'] = v.max(1) - v.min(1)
df

    A   B    C   D   E
0  21  34   55  43  aa
1  24  53   77  65  bb
2  77  23  100  34  cc
3  31  54   43  23  dd
4  44  23   67  54  ee
5  75  43   98  23  ff
```